# sh: cannot create /dev/null/: Not a directory

Tags: bash

I am having an issue where a

```
bash script.sh &> /dev/null/
```

call is throwing this error. /dev/null does exist and I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to be a directory anyway. A quick google search shows that I'm the only one to ever post this exact error so... that's fun.

Comment: Have you tried to remove that final slash? `bash script.sh &> /dev/null` ?

Comment: `/a/b/` is not the same thing as `/a/b`. In some contexts, the first expression means `b` is a directory.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, simply remove the trailing `/`

Because `/dev/null/` is a not existing directory.

Comment: I'll give that a go. It's just a bit bizarre because this script was running fine until I migrated everything over to a new system.

Comment: That appears to have done it - although now output from the underlying curl script is finding it's way into the log file. Which it isn't meant to and is why I had &> /dev/null.